# How do I get getpwuid to work in my mac app?

Tags: macos, mac-app-store, getpwuid

I'm trying to get my sandboxed mac app to get to the user's real home folder.

This is what I tried

```
const char *home = getpwent()->pw_dir;
NSString *path = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] 
              stringWithFileSystemRepresentation:home
              length:strlen(home)];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path isDirectory:YES];
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Member reference type 'int' is not a pointer
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to

```
 #include <pwd.h>
```

I'll leave the question up in case someone else has trouble with it!